# Attached Property siempre tiene el valor por defecto en style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

Estoy trabajando con WPF, y estoy intentando usar Attached Properties para trabajar algunos detalles de estética de mis controles (específicamente, lo que respecta a validaciones).

Para explicar mi problema, debo agregar algo de código..

Mi Attached Property

```
public class ToolTipExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowToolTipProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ShowToolTip", typeof(string), typeof(ToolTipExtension), new PropertyMetadata("Deffault"));    

    public static void SetShowToolTip(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ShowToolTipProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetShowToolTip(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(ShowToolTipProperty);
    }    
}
```

Mi diccionario es algo sencillo, como el siguiente:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:at="clr-namespace:CarpetaTecnicaWPF.AttachedProperties"
                    >   
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="Blah" >
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip)}" FontSize="50"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Como se puede ver en el diccionario, intento bindear la propiedad `Text` con el valor de mi Attached Property, aplico el estilo de la siguiente manera:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Blah}" at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip="Prueba?"/>
```

El problema es el siguiente, el valor `Prueba?` simplemente, no aparece, y al intentar usar el Árbol Visual Dinámico, me encuentro con lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo perfecto, la propiedad tiene el valor que yo espero..

Pero para mi sorpresa, la vista renderiza lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar, que `Deffault` es el valor por defecto de mi AttachedProperty

[Pregunta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626231/attached-property-always-has-a-default-value-in-a-style/57626675?noredirect=1#comment101707241_57626675)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El bindeo es incorrecto.

El `TemplatedParent` no es lo correcto en este caso. El `ControlTemplate` para el error no se aplica al mismo `TextBox`, es un `ControlTemplate` independiente, por ende.. nunca es seteado, entonces, devuelve el valor por defecto del `FrameworkElement` que está siendo consultado.

Para aceder a la información del `TextBox` desde el `ControlTemplate` de error es necesario usar `AdornedElementPlaceholder`, desde este, podremos acceder a las propiedades del `TextBox` mediante la propiedad `AdornedElement`.

Por ejemplo:

```
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(at:ToolTipExtension.ShowToolTip)}"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

[Respuesta de dymanoid en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626675/5213794)